# probability functions in scala

Tags: scala, probability, normal-distribution

I want to compute the probability that a normally distributed random number with given parameters (mean and std) will be less than a given number or list.
This function is implemented in R as "pnorm".
Does anyone know if such an option or can help me write one please?

Comment: http://jliszka.github.io/2013/08/12/a-frequentist-approach-to-probability.html

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/NormalDistribution.html

Answer (score 2):

The probability that a normally distributed quantity (with a variance of 1/2) is greater than a particular value is given by a special function call the [complementary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Complementary_error_function), often denoted erfc().

I don't think there's any support for computing erfc() within the Scala [math](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/math/index.html) library. However, the Apache Commons Math library does have functions for computing [erfc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/special/Erf.html)(). If you're interested in processing multiple values, there is also the erfc() method available within the [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet#error-function) library.

If you have a means of computing erfc(x), for a distribution with mean mu and standard-deviation sigma, the probability your deviate is less than a value z is

```
0.5 * erfc((mu - z) / (sigma * sqrt(2)))
```